# Simply calling window.getComputedStyle() doesn't trigger redraw without reading a property?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I can't seem to track down the answer in the specs or here on SO. It seems to me that simply invoking the `getComputedSyle` method doesn't trigger a redraw, but rather you have to read one of the properties of the returned `CSSStyleDeclaration` object before the draw actually happens. Do I have that right? If so, what is the explanation for that? Is there some sort of getter mechanism built into those properties?

Comment: Yes there is "some sort of getter mechanism built into those properties" and it's one of the most important things to know when optimizing a web site because interleaving changes and reads is how you get too many reflows (ie: if you read and the property changed a reflow is necessary, and a reflow is very expensive).

Comment: If the `Element.style` object is also of the `CSSStyleDeclaration` prototype, why is a redraw not triggered by reading properties on that object?